# Salesforce Marketing Cloud SSJS: Unable to fetch the HttpRequest response

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

I am using the below SSJS code.

```
  var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(eventEndPoint);

      req.emptyContentHandling = 0;

      req.retries = 2;

      req.continueOnError = true;

      //req.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

      req.setHeader("Authorization",BearerToken);

      req.method = "GET";

  var getResponse = req.send();

  var content = getResponse.content
```

For **content** variable, I am getting the below response

```
{

    "checking": "{\"count\":2,\"page\":1,\"pageSize\":50,\"links\":{},\"items\":[{\"id\":\"e999c177-59af-4945-ab8f-d391a09ba19f\",\"type\":\"EmailAudience\",\"name\":\"Case Creation and Assignment JB\",\"description\":\"\",\"createdDate\":\"2018-06-11T21:26:16.157\",\"createdBy\":7569295,\"modifiedDate\":\"2018-06-11T22:44:31.26\",\"modifiedBy\":7569295,\"mode\":\"Production\",\"eventDefinitionKey\":\"DEAudience-e0366f83-fde7-aa69-fe47-f6e663e1be34\",\"dataExtensionId\":\"7898ff4b-406d-e811-80d4-1402ec722051\",\"dataExtensionName\":\"Contacts Synchronised Shared DE Automation\",\"sourceApplicationExtensionId\":\"97e942ee-6914-4d3d-9e52-37ecb71f79ed\",\"filterDefinitionId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"filterDefinitionTemplate\":\"\",\"iconUrl\":\"/images/icon-data-extension.svg\",\"arguments\":{\"serializedObjectType\":3,\"serializedObjectType\":3,\"eventDefinitionId\":\"e999c177-59af-4945-ab8f-d391a09ba19f\",\"eventDefinitionKey\":\"DEAudience-e0366f83-fde7-aa69-fe47-f6e663e1be34\",\"dataExtensionId\":\"7898ff4b-406d-e811-80d4-1402ec722051\",\"automationId\":\"dd1c4419-16cb-41b5-bc40-c00e1256b41d\",\"criteria\":\"\",\"useHighWatermark\":false},\"configurationArguments\":{\"unconfigured\":false},\"metaData\":{\"scheduleState\":\"No Schedule\",\"criteriaDescription\":\"\",\"scheduleFlowMode\":\"runOnce\",\"runOnceScheduleMode\":\"onPublish\"},\"interactionCount\":0,\"isVisibleInPicker\":false,\"isPlatformObject\":false,\"category\":\"Audience\",\"publishedInteractionCount\":0,\"automationId\":\"dd1c4419-16cb-41b5-bc40-c00e1256b41d\",\"disableDEDataLogging\":false},{\"id\":\"7be8062a-afb6-4f38-8fe8-7642faef79e5\",\"type\":\"EmailAudience\",\"name\":\"Case Creation and Assignment JB (copy)\",\"description\":\"\",\"createdDate\":\"2018-06-11T22:53:56.19\",\"createdBy\":7569295,\"modifiedDate\":\"2018-06-11T23:27:52.96\",\"modifiedBy\":7569295,\"mode\":\"Production\",\"eventDefinitionKey\":\"DEAudience-10fdbbff-c175-5eeb-3486-482649574d22\",\"dataExtensionId\":\"7898ff4b-406d-e811-80d4-1402ec722051\",\"dataExtensionName\":\"Contacts Synchronised Shared DE Automation\",\"sourceApplicationExtensionId\":\"97e942ee-6914-4d3d-9e52-37ecb71f79ed\",\"filterDefinitionId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"filterDefinitionTemplate\":\"\",\"iconUrl\":\"/images/icon-data-extension.svg\",\"arguments\":{\"serializedObjectType\":3,\"serializedObjectType\":3,\"eventDefinitionId\":\"7be8062a-afb6-4f38-8fe8-7642faef79e5\",\"eventDefinitionKey\":\"DEAudience-10fdbbff-c175-5eeb-3486-482649574d22\",\"dataExtensionId\":\"7898ff4b-406d-e811-80d4-1402ec722051\",\"automationId\":\"ce0e033f-bce7-466e-bae9-48573572db20\",\"criteria\":\"\",\"useHighWatermark\":false},\"configurationArguments\":{\"unconfigured\":false},\"metaData\":{\"scheduleState\":\"No Schedule\",\"criteriaDescription\":\"\",\"scheduleFlowMode\":\"runOnce\",\"runOnceScheduleMode\":\"onPublish\"},\"interactionCount\":2,\"isVisibleInPicker\":false,\"isPlatformObject\":false,\"category\":\"Audience\",\"publishedInteractionCount\":0,\"automationId\":\"ce0e033f-bce7-466e-bae9-48573572db20\",\"disableDEDataLogging\":false}]}"

}
```

I want to fetch the **checking.items[0][id]** value, for that I am doing JSON parse using **Platform.Function.ParseJSON(content)** but it's not working. Is there anything I am missing?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before parsing the results of your request you need to turn it into the string:

```js
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");

    var checking = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(getResponse.content));

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Niko this is working now.